# Can VR and NVR camera put into a same scene after switching a scene?

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, virtual-reality

I have tried to run a unity scene which consist an VR camera and NVR camera that can switch to
each other when mount/dismount a VR headset. It works fine first when testing, but this feature
fails to work when start playing the Unity project from other scene. Does anyone have this idea
about this problem?